# How to configure "Proxy user request" for NiFi CLI

Tags: apache-nifi

According to the documentation, one prerequisite for using NiFi CLI against a secured NiFi instance is to configure proxy user request for the node's identity (e.g. CN=localhost, OU=NIFI).

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/toolkit-guide.html#prerequisites-for-running-in-a-secure-environment

I understand how to configure it through the NiFi web user interface. However, is it possible to do the same through scripting?

The reason is that I am working on a NiFi installation script, and I would like to install NiFi and configure users/policies in one go if it is possible.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to use NiFi CLI to setup NiFi itself, then you're only real option is for NiFi CLI to perform operations as the Initial Admin identity.

It then depends how NiFi is configured to perform authentication, meaning where is your initial admin identity coming from. Is it a DN from a client cert, a user in LDAP, a kerberos principal, etc?

If it is a client cert, then you can just configure NiFi CLI to use that cert and it should work.

If it is a LDAP user, then you need to have NiFi CLI use one of NiFi's server certs to proxy the LDAP user.

Both of these scenarios are shown in the docs:

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/toolkit-guide.html#security-configuration

Comment: Hello Bryan. Thanks for your answer! I am using a client cert for the initial admin. I had tried converting the admin P12 file to a JKS keystore and configuring the property file following the "without Proxied-Entity" example. It was unsuccessful although I don't remember the specific errors. Am I on the right track, or have I misunderstood the documentation?

Comment: That is correct approach, you should be able to use P12 or JKS with CLI, just set the keystoreType appropriately to JKS or PKCS12.